# Very weird problems involving pointer member variables and polymorphism

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, polymorphism

Okay, so I'm experiencing some very weird issues with storing an array of base class pointers in a class then settings this base class pointers equal to some dynamically allocated derived class pointers.
My code is too long and bloated with GUI calls to post here, so I'll make some mock code here that demonstrates the methodology I'm using

Base Class - Base

```
class Base
{

public:
    Base(){ // do nothing}
    virtual void SetUI(){ // do nothing}


}
```

Derived Class - Derived

```
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived() : Base() { // do nothing}
    virtual void SetUI(){// do nothing}

}
```

This is a class that basically holds data for my program, it contains an array of pointers to the base class. These pointers are initialized by having them point to dynamically created objects of the derived class type.

```
class HelperClass
{
private:
    Base * basearray[2];

public:
    HelperClass()
    {
     basearray[0] = new Derived;
     basearray[1] = new Derived;
    }

    Base * getBaseArray(int key)
    {
    return this->basearray[key];
    }
}
```

here is my "main", this is where everything starts getting weird.

```
int main()
{
 HelperClass hold;
 hold.getBaseArray(0)->setUI();
 // NOTHING HAPPENS ABOVE, THE CODE DOESN'T EVEN REACH THIS POINT, IT JUST GET'S LOST SOMEWHERE IN     //THE ABOVE STATEMENT.  i KNOW THIS BECAUSE I PUT AN exit(0) inside the function setUI() for both the   //base and derived class and the program doesn't exit.

// this also does nothing
 if(hold->getBaseArray(0) || !hold->getBaseArray(0))
    exit(0);

return 0;
}
```

but oddly enough, if i do something like the following, where I just declare a base class pointer and have it point to a dynamically created object of the derived class, everything works just fine.

```
int main()
{
 Base *hold;
 hold = new Derived;
 hold->setUI(); // <- this works polymorphically


return 0;
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why my program stops working when I try to work with the array of base class pointers inside the HelperClass? When I try to do getBaseArray(int) it doesn't return anything,  which causes statements like

```
if(hold->getBaseArray(0) || !hold->getBaseArray(0)) {exit(0);}
```

to not make the program exit, which is weird because the pointer that getBaseArray() returns is either null or non-null, which means the program should exit no matter what

Comment: There is *way* too much code here to wade through. Please be a little more specific about where the error is occurring and what the actual symptom is.

Comment: You should create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: `if(DPSimSettings->getPlot1() || !SimSettings->getPlot1())` - you use different objects to call methods

Comment: okay, sorry I figured I would put everything because people normally end up asking for more code. The problem is essentially in the last 3 code blocks, the third to last one shows the class that has the array of base class pointers. The second to last shows the implementation of that class. The last one shows where I'm trying to use the polymorphism

Comment: AndyT sorry that was my mistake in copying the code, I deleted some things that didnt have anything to do with the problem and accidentally deleted the name and then rewrote it wrong. I can assure you in my project those two names are the same

Comment: okay guy's I shortened the code to exclude the class definitions and all member functions that don't have to do with the problem area.

Comment: [Here is an SSCCE that demonstrates that this program works correctly after correcting syntax.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4949492c9d061346) The problem is in code you are not showing us.

Comment: thank you for your patience Casey, I seriously have no idea what is wrong if that works correctly, because thatcode is (as far as I can tell) directly analogous to the code I'm working with. The main difference I can see is that my real code is using the windows API and thus there is no main fuction, in my code this is happening inside of callback procedures but the principle should be the same. I'm tearing my hair out over here

Answer (score 1):

I (and my compiler) found two mistackes you have in the first `main()`

1. You declare `SetUI()` in your Base and Derived class, but in the `main` you try to call `setUI()`. Perhaps you have both functions in your project and that's why you recieved nothing.
2. You declare `hold` as an object and not a pointer. With this you can not do like `hold->someFn()`. You should call thet like `hold.someFn()`.

Here is the code with corrections. It runs by me without problems. Try it.

```
struct Base
{
    Base(){}
    virtual ~Base() {}
    virtual void SetUI() {
        cout << "base" << endl;
    }
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
    Derived() : Base() {}
    virtual ~Derived() {}
    virtual void SetUI() {
        cout << "derived" << endl;
    }
};

class HelperClass
{
    Base * basearray[2];

public:
    HelperClass() {
        basearray[0] = new Derived;
        basearray[1] = new Derived;
    }
    ~HelperClass() {
        delete basearray[0];
        delete basearray[1];
    }

    Base *getBaseArray(int key) {
        return basearray[key];
    }
};

int main()
{
 HelperClass hold;
 hold.getBaseArray(0)->SetUI();

 if(hold.getBaseArray(0))
     cout << "some output" << endl;

return 0;
}
```